# bash script automysql sees greater-than character as a table name

Tags: mysql, bash

```
CMD="mysqldump -usomeuser -psomepass db_name \> /../SQL_$(date +'%m-%d-%Y').sql"
```

The above throws the following exception:

> mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"

"&1>" also is seen as a table name.

I tried the option -all-database(s) and that doesn't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply escaping using \> is seen as a table name too. Thx!

Comment: How is the string "CMD" being executed?  Is it possible to execute the statement directly in the bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You must not escape greater-than in the command:

```
CMD="mysqldump -usomeuser -psomepass db_name > /../SQL_$(date +'%m-%d-%Y').sql"
```

even then, if you try to execute the command just by invoking it, bash treats the greater-than as a positional parameter. You can execute it with a call to sh or bash:

```
bash -c "$CMD"
```

Comment: I originally did not escape the greater-than symbol and still had the same problem. See my first comment after the original post.

Comment: I will be revisiting this in a few weeks. I'll probably ditch the bash language and go with PERL of PHP5. If this post is not closed, I will update it with my progress.